# How to run shell command in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, shell

I want to run shell command using NSButton in Swift. The IBAaction and execute function I use cannot work, pls help me, thanks!

```
    @IBAction func Openfolder(_ sender: NSButton) {
     _ = execute(command:"open " + "~/Downloads/")
}


func execute(command: String) -> String {
     var arguments:[String] = []
     arguments.append("-c")
     arguments.append( command )

     let task = Process()
     task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
     task.arguments = arguments

     let pipe = Pipe()
     task.standardOutput = pipe
     task.standardError = pipe
     task.launch()
     task.waitUntilExit()
     let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

     return(NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String)
 }
```

Comment: What does not work? Why do you ignore the result (the potential error) ? And you can replace the *spaghetti-init* `NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String` with `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!`

Comment: Thanks for your help. The result I want to achieve is that when I click the button, the Downloads folder can be opened, but the nothing happened.

Comment: I try another funtion,    @IBAction func Openfloder(_ sender: NSButton) {
        let path = "/bin/sh"
        let arguments = ["-c", "open" + " /Users/***/Downloads/"]
        sender.isEnabled = false
        let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
        task.waitUntilExit()
        sender.isEnabled = true
    }    Error Result is LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -54 for the file

Comment: Try simpler `let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/open")` `try? Process.run(url, arguments: ["/Users/****/Downloads"], terminationHandler: nil)`. But consider that if the app is sandboxed you can't run shell scripts, however you can open the Downloads folder with `NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)` if you enable the appropriate capabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I turn off the sandbox and the command run successfully. But I don't know what the role sandbox, can you give me a reference?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/